# Hibernate HQL join for joined table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to create HQL query, here it is:

```
     query = "SELECT test From Result result " +
                    "JOIN result.test test JOIN result.user user " +
                    "WHERE test.id = :testId AND user.id = :userId " +
                    "AND result.permission.id = :permissionId"),
```

and now i want to add additional for questions (many to one with test) and answers (many to one with questions). If I try something like this:

```
     query = "SELECT test From Result result " +
                    "JOIN result.test test JOIN result.user user JOIN test.questions as question" +
                    "WHERE test.id = :testId AND user.id = :userId " +
                    "AND result.permission.id = :permissionId")
```

i am getting an exeption.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: getCurrentTestById
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:545) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 190 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error here (need a space)

```
"JOIN result.test test JOIN result.user user JOIN test.questions as question"
```

I wonder why do you need a join on questions...you don't use it in the where.

Comment: i want to use question option, for example question.deleted = false